# Issue converting array to array list

Tags: java

Trying to write a java code for a single row Battleship style game, and when I tried to convert from an array to an ArrayList, the game started returning "miss" no matter what.

```
public class SimpleDotComGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numofGuess = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();
        int ranNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
        ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        locations.add(ranNum);
        locations.add(ranNum + 1);
        locations.add(ranNum + 2);
        dot.setLocationCells(locations); //think like you're running a
            // separate program with parameters to set cells as "locations"
        boolean isAlive = true;
        while (isAlive == true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            String userGuess = sc.next();
            String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess); //run program to
                // check if cells were hit by userGuess
            numofGuess++;
            if (result.equals("kill")) {
                isAlive = false;
                System.out.println("You took " + numofGuess + " guesses");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class SimpleDotCom {
    int numofHits = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> locationCells;
    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<Integer> locations) { //locations
            // variable described array so we must define it as array now
        locationCells = locations;
    }
    public String checkYourself(String userGuess) { //check using parameter userGuess
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(userGuess);
        String result = "miss";
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userGuess);
        if (index >= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);
            if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                result = "kill";
            } else {
                result = "hit";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR please provide the relevant code to detect the issue.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I'm very new to this and I'm not sure what you're asking. I'm sorry, just trying to learn.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm very new to this and I don't even know what the issue is you're asking me to correct.

Comment: I mean that by posting a wall of code you won't get that much help for readers. Please understand that this site is to get and give free help, so people here use their own time to help other people. So, please evaluate your code and post only the part where the issue appears. If you're not really sure on what to post, try to reproduce the issue in a new class (or classes) and post that code here (this is known as [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so the code is to the point and it's easier for us to understand and help you and for you to apply the solution given.

Comment: I rolled back because your edit inadvertently removed too much of your code.

Comment: Also, you should never use a magic string value as a return--the advantage of a strongly-typed system such as Java is avoiding the possible mistake of returning `mis`. Use an enum for this sort of situation; basic enums are very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
int index = locationCells.indexOf(userGuess);
```

to

```
int index = locationCells.indexOf(guess);
```

userGuess is a String which can not possibly be in a list of Integers. guess is an int which can.

Comment: Perfect! We're up and running. Thank you!

Comment: @L.Seymour This would have been avoided if you'd used a proper parameter type of `int`/`Integer` instead of pretending a `String` is a number. Parse it with your input, then pass around the proper data type.

Comment: @chrylis I'm sorry, I may not understand. Do you mean that I should parse my userGuess before I set it in the SimpleDotCom class, or is there an additional String variable in which I should have parsed?

Comment: @L.Seymour Yes: Instead of `String checkYourself(String)`, which takes something that's a number and returns something that's an enumerated value, you should have `HitResult checkYourself(int guess)`, where `HitResult` is something like `enum HitResult { MISS, HIT, KILL }`.

Comment: @chrylis That's interesting. I'm so new to this that I hadn't even heard of that. Read online about it and it makes so much more sense. Thank you so much.